# C# - Auto suggestions in chat bot using Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am trying to implement auto Question-suggestions Pop-Up in chatbot using Bot Framework in C#. how to keep multiple auto Question suggestions Pop-Up in a single row. when I enter the hi(text field) it gives the multiple suggestion(like hello, hey there,hi etc.) and click on suggestion it will auto complete it , It should be like Google suggestion.

I 'm implemented in C#,But it give suggestion with multiple answer.Here is below my sample code

```
[QnAMaker("set yout subscription key here", "set your kbid here", "I don't understand this right now! Try another query!", 0.50, 3)]
    public class QnABotWithCustomAnswer : QnAMakerDialog
    {
        protected override async Task QnAFeedbackStepAsync(IDialogContext context, QnAMakerResults qnaMakerResults)
        {
            // responding with the top answer when score is above some threshold
            if (qnaMakerResults.Answers.Count > 0 && qnaMakerResults.Answers.FirstOrDefault().Score > 0.75)
            {
                await context.PostAsync(qnaMakerResults.Answers.FirstOrDefault().Answer);
            }
            else
            {
                await base.QnAFeedbackStepAsync(context, qnaMakerResults);
            }
        }
}
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

> it give suggestion with multiple answer

In your code, we can find that you set `top` property (the number of answers to return) to **3**, if you want your QnAMaker dialog return top 1 answer, you can set `top` property to **1**.

```
[QnAMaker("{subscriptionKey_here}", "{ knowledgebaseId_here}", "I don't understand this right now! Try another query!", 0.50, 1)]
```

Here is the definition of QnAMakerAttribute, you can check it and know the details of each parameters:

```
// Summary:
//     Construct the QnA Knowledgebase information.
//
// Parameters:
//   knowledgebaseId:
//     The QnA Knowledgebase ID.
//
//   defaultMessage:
//     The default message returned when no match found.
//
//   scoreThreshold:
//     The threshold for answer score.
//
//   top:
//     The number of answers to return.
public QnAMakerAttribute(string authKey, string knowledgebaseId, string defaultMessage = null, double scoreThreshold = 0.3, int top = 1, string endpointHostName = null);
```